# oracle 12c grid standalone Installation failed with crsconfig_params file not found error in windows

Tags: oracle, oracle-12c, installation

Oracle 12c grid installation failed (39% progressed) with "crsconfig_params file not found" error in Windows operating system:

[image: Error screen capture]

Can we abort the session or need to fix and retry the session?

Please share your advice.

Comment: Please check firewall and antivirus status. Both of them should be stop dureing installation.

Comment: Disabled the firewall and other Antivirus software's bur still no luck..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure of unzip the grid installer in just one directory. For example, if the files you need to unzip are the following: winx64_1202_grid1of2.zip and winx64_1202_grid2of2.zip, then unzip both of them on the Grid directory and install from there.